# When a user click ‘add to cart’ on a product the item does get added to the cart

Tags: woocommerce

when a user click ‘add to cart’ on a product the item added to shopping cart (ajax works), but the number shown in the menu at the top remains at (0) until you refresh the page or go to another page. is there any way to get it to update onclick dynamically immediately?

Comment: you may try using callback from [here](https://docs.woothemes.com/document/wc_api-the-woocommerce-api-callback/).

Comment: that is not a woocommerce feature... you should show us your code.. and what have you tried so far...

Comment: I've copied storefront shopping cart in my theme

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the following filter

```
woocommerce_add_to_cart_fragments
```

here's an example of how to get the current total cart items after adding a product to cart via ajax.

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_add_to_cart_fragments', 'my_cart_link_fragment' );
    if ( ! function_exists( 'my_cart_link_fragment' ) ) {
        function my_cart_link_fragment( $fragments ) {
            global $woocommerce;

            ob_start();

            <span class="count"><?php echo wp_kses_data( sprintf( _n( '%d', '%d', WC()->cart->get_cart_contents_count(), 'storefront' ), WC()->cart->get_cart_contents_count() ) );?></span>


            $fragments['a.cart-contents'] = ob_get_clean();

            return $fragments;
        }
```

put the code above into your functions.php